# Do any versions of macOS perform "SSD data block swapping" to avoid SSD fatigue?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, ssd

I heard that SSD drives can become fatigued and have data errors, if the same data block is used for reading and writing to many times.  So, there are mechanisms to swap the often used blocks with the less often used blocks.

One reference about SSD endurance and wear leveling is on [this page](https://www.atpinc.com/blog/trim-garbage-collection-ssd-endurance-wai-waf).

For example, if a Mac had only 10 GB left on the SSD, then this 10 GB could be repeatedly used to download and move files to NAS, or as swap space for virtual memory.

Does the current macOS perform the SSD swapping to avoid the fatigue? If so, then with which version of macOS did this first occur? Or, does the Mac's internal SSD use low-level firmware to avoid the fatigue in way transparent to macOS?

Comment: Any sources for the stuff you “heard”?

Comment: nonpolarity: What makes you think macOS (or any other OS) does swapping? Are you assuming reading causes the same amount of fatigue as writing?

Comment: @SolarMike it was just about 8 years when SSD was used as hard drives and some blog post was saying there might be problems when it is read / write too many times, and then one or two year later, some other tech blog post stated that there is swapping mechanism so now we can be less worried about it

Comment: nonpolarity: Please see https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment about the purpose of comments and why they are useful in shaping questions.

Comment: @nohillside I don't think he is shaping the question

Comment: The question as asked is based on rumors and assumptions, such questions usually get downvoted and don't attract good answers. Please take the feedback you get in comments as clues on how to improve the question.

Comment: it is not based on rumors. Anybody who knows SSD to a certain degree know the data blocks are swapped to increase the SSD life

Comment: Why do you think it is the OS that does "SSD swapping" (and what exactly is that I have not heard of that term). Doesn't the SSD actually do this at least garbage collection https://uk.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/ssd-used-to-be-faster-but-has-slowed-down

Comment: one reason I thought about the OS, was that I did those "Disk Defragmentation" before during the PC era.  The OS moves the blocks around, very much like how SSD would need to be "leveled"

Comment: Disk defragmentation is a completely different thing - and happens on a whole other level of the system. Doing disk defragmentation on an SSD will actually increase the wear on the disk - not reduce it - and it won't give you the performance increase that you were hoping for. Disk defragmentation is for traditional "spinning platters" disks, where it matters for performance whether logical coherent data is stored consecutively or non-consecutively.

Comment: Disk Defragmentation is certainly a different thing.  I mentioned it because some people keep asking why I think SSD Wear Leveling happens at the OS level. It seems they might know the answer, but instead of just saying "Wear Leveling happens at the SSD firmware level and computer's OS doesn't participate in it, so don't worry about the macOS version". -- instead of saying this, they just question, "Why do you think it happens at the OS level", and some thinks that wear leveling is a rumor

Comment: @nonopolarity The trouble is you are using terms like "SSD swapping" which are just not known so we have to ask you for more details and find out what you are assuming, and also where you heard things as wear issue were true for the first SSDs 10+ years ago but are not a real problem now. The internet does not delete old incorrect information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Wear Leveling

This functionality is actually contained within the Solid State Drive (SSD) itself and known as [wear levelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wear_leveling). It has been standard on all Macs that have had SSDs - i.e. for many, many years.

I remember back in approx. 2008 when replacing the internal hard drive of the MacBook Air with a third-party SSD, you had to look out not to buy an older model SSD without wear levelling - but since then it has been a feature that is just always there on an SSD.

### Operating System Agnostic

The functionality does not depend on operating system support, so any version of macOS will do. If your system otherwise supports it, running under Windows or Linux is also just fine.

### Free Space

Also the functionality does not depend on having "free space" on your drive. It doesn't matter if you have 10 GB of free space or 1000 GB of free space. It works just the same.

Comment: so it has very low level of "wear leveling", I'd assume.  I asked if the OS participate in it, because for example, if the OS can move a 1GB file to another place, it can do a lot of leveling all at once, so it is like leveling that can be done by firmware, assisted by the OS. But I think if the firmware (of the SSD) can already do a good job at silently leveling all 10GB of the hard drive's free space little by little, then the OS assistance will not be needed

Comment: No, that's not really how this stuff works. SSD on Macs function the exact same way as they do on Windows, Linux and other systems. The "very low level wear levelling" is actually how it is done on all systems. You want the drive controller to be able to that autonomously as otherwise the operating system would need to know all sorts of details about the drive. When a drive is advertised as 512 GB for example, that is only a very superficial description of the actual disk. In reality the amount of space available to the disk controller is higher, and it performs all sorts of duties to maintain

Comment: health of the disk drive as a whole. The wear levelling is not performed on the "hard drive's free space". In fact, for a very long time it was very common that SSDs had no notion at all of which space on the drive was "occupied" or "free". In modern times, variations of functionality known as UNMAP or TRIM makes it possible for the operating system to tell the drive controller that specific disk blocks are no longer used (i.e. they're "free"). This functionality is not needed in order to do wear levelling, however it does enable the drive controller to do things differently in order to gain

Comment: performance, and especially reduce write amplification.

Comment: so the external SSD manufacturer, be it Samsung in Korea, or ASUS in Taiwan, they all have this technology... it seems pretty difficult to do, but I'd suppose they can also buy the technology from some other company, and perhaps many SSD manufacturers use the same or similar firmware underneath

Comment: Yes, they all have that technology. Why do you think it is "pretty difficult"? - in its concept, it is quite straight forward. The technique in general has been used for decades - also before consumer SSDs were a thing. And no, they do not use the same firmware underneath - the various drives produces vary quite a lot in terms of the actual hardware used, as well as in how date is stored, moved around, encrypted, transferred, etc.

Comment: I think it is difficult because it is already down to the Operating System level, and like you said, the SSD has no notion whether the space is occupied or free... it is quite deep... I never heard of such thing before. When I took my CS degree, some of my classmates get A+ in other computer classes, but when it got to OS programming, they struggled to get a B, and even worse when they took compiler design. The SSD firmware also needs to be extremely precise and bug free, or else a tiny bug can make the whole SSD data store corrupted

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with the operating system level. This occurs below the level of the operating system. That the SSD has no notion whether the space is occupied or free does not make the problem harder - if anything, it makes it easier to do. I cannot say why your CS curriculum did not include information about disk controllers, but it is not exactly "black magic" or "secret knowledge" in any way. This is not something that is "much harder to do" or "much more complex" than other things in CS. It is ofcourse more complex than getting a browser to display "Hello World", but

Comment: significantly less complex than implementing a full Bluetooth stack for example. And no, the SSD firmware does not need to be "extremely precise and bug free" - in practice, lots of bugs have been found in SSD firmwares and it is continues to be that way. Why else would effort be spent in updating the firmware of such SSDs :-) And yes, a tiny bug can make a whole SSD corrupted in some sense... but that can also be said of a tiny bug in many other places. Ofcourse a manufacturer will ensure and test that the common paths in the firmware code are unlikely to leave the disk corrupted.

Comment: As I get the feeling that you're being introduced to the "brave new world" of disk controllers, you might get a kick out of knowing that even the very tiny micro-SD cards also include a disk controller that does wear levelling very similar to that of a "full" SSD.

Comment: No, I don't mean "exactly operating system level". I mean it is "like" OS: low level. So while we can write Angry Birds or the Facebook app with an A+, we struggled quite a bit when it went down to low level programming, is all I am saying

Comment: Ah - well, I think it might have been a coincidence that all of you were "coming from the same place" - having the same experiences, etc. I don't think there's anything inherently  more difficult about low level programming than high level programming. Some people like one more than the other, but it really varies from person to person, what they're most comfortable with. I certainly know a lot of programmers that are very comfortable with "low level" programming of embedded systems, operating systems, etc. - that have a very hard time working with high level programming, such as an iOS app.

Comment: I remember one of our OS projects was "a lightweight threading system" and it was quite abstract.  Anyway, I just thought about one possible big issue of the SSD firmware: time and again, I plugged in my SSD to the side of the MacBook, but when I move the MacBook around, I might accidentally  detach the USB plug (type A), and the SSD just outright gets cut off from electricity. So isn't it really dangerous if it is doing leveling right at this moment? Or if there is "journaling" that makes it more safe. The leveling has to happen as one unit or that it never happened

Comment: Yanking a disk without unmounting it is always "dangerous". However in regards to wear levelling inside the SSD, there's no specific threat there. Wear levelling usually works by writing the data in a new location and then updating a a "link" to the new data in a mapping table. If the power is cut when doing this, the new block of data could have been partially or fully written, but not yet mapped - this means that the old block of data will be used when repowered - i.e. as if the write never took place. In practice, modern SSDs have (super-)capacitors to provide power for completing

Comment: outstanding writes when the power is cut.